# Launch Google Play Games App using WEBINTENT plugin

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-build, webintents

I want to open Google play games app on my mobile from my android phonegap build application using WEBINTENT plugin.

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
  action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
  url: 'facebook://'
},
function() {alert('success')}, 
function(errorMsg) {alert('Failed to startActivity errorMsg=' + errorMsg)}
);

},false);
```

This code works well to open facebook.
How to use it to open play games application.?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web intent plugin can only open apps that have an url scheme to open it.

if the games you want to open don't have an url scheme, then you can't open them with the web intent plugin

You can use the startapp plugin to open apps using the package name

https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp

To use it on phonegap build, add this on the config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.lampa.startapp" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

To open an app use this code:

```
navigator.startApp.check("com.package.name", function(message) { /* success */
    console.log(message); // => OK
}, 
function(error) { /* error */
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Ok.I am using phonegap build..But the phonegap build startapp plugin does not contain any usage instructions..how do i proceed...OR what all files i need to move from that repository and where do i move them to use the plugin...thanks??

Comment: The plugin from phonegap build doesn't seem to open app by package. The one I told you is on plugins.cordova.io, this plugins can be used from phonegap build too http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.lampa.startapp

Comment: I will check that out.Thanku.And is there any plugin with which i can send data and access google play games leaderboards with phonegap build.?thanks. @jcesarmobile

Comment: you have this plugin, but I didn't try it http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.a42.cordova.googleplaygame

Comment: Ok i will try this one.And your previous answer works exactly fine.Opens the app for me.I am opening play games app.How do i open a specific game in that using this code?

Comment: Could u tell me where do i specify my app ID using this cordova.googleplaygame plugin.??? Thanks. @jcesarmobile

Comment: try adding the plugin like this: <gap:plugin name="com.a42.cordova.googleplaygame"  source="plugins.cordova.io" >
  <param name="APP_ID" value="yourAppID" />
</gap:plugin>

Comment: the plugin isnt getting added...how do i proceed now???The log file shows errors in java file. @jcesarmobile

Comment: You should create a new question and provide information about the java errors

Comment: i would do that...but how would i update the plugin later after the errors in the plugin java file get fixed..?

Comment: everytime you build the app, it gets the java files and compile them, so when it get fixed, you app will compile

Comment: I am able to open the googleplaygames application using the startapp plugin.How do i open a particular game on that application directly using this plugin??? @jcesarmobile

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: ok.I tried using the googleplaygames plugins from plugins.cordova.io....But all of them have a commandline instalation...So while using them on phonegapbuild i keep getting errors or builds fail.I've logged the issue to pgb support and havent received any responses yet...how do i proceed now??? @jcesarmobile

Comment: o stop using phonegap build and start doing local development

Comment: The apps performance is decreasing while building locally while it performs well using phonegap build...

Comment: What? That shouldn't happen, I've been building locally for years and never noticed decrease on the performance

Comment: I am using the same code..But there is lag in the app when built locally......Should i make any changes to any of the manifest or config.xml files..??? @jcesarmobile

Comment: Sorry, I can't help, I've never had lag in the app, I don't do anything special

Comment: Ok..i downloaded the android sdk...and have run the cordova create and all commands to create the project...i added my code and i am running it on my device from eclipse......Is this the procedure or is there something else i need to do?? @jcesarmobile

Comment: you don't need eclipse, but using eclipse shouldn't make the app go slower either.

Comment: ok i will look upon that.......Is Appcelerator better than Phonegap???....I am asking because i've heard phonegap dosent give a native feel wheras Appcelerator Titanium does....

Comment: well, I can't say if it's better of worse, it's different. You build the whole app with javascript. It's supposed to be faster. On phonegap you build the interface with html, css and javascript, on titanium you use existing components with javascript

Comment: Is Appcelerator open sourced like phonegap....Or i need to pay to build and deploy apps to playstore...?

Comment: it's opensource and free